# Bearer Token extraction from request django

Tags: python, django

If I have a post request with this JSON :

```
{
  "user_id":230,
  "name":"Anthony"
}
```

I can extract the name by :

```py
name = json.loads(request.body).get("name")
```

Now I have a `GET` request in which I am passing bearer token.

How should I extract it in Django?

Comment: Then the parameter is in the *querystring*.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the authorization header with `request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`